# $|x|<1/2$ and $|y|\le1\Rightarrow|4x^2y-y-x|<17/16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given that: $|x|<1/2$ and $|y|\le1$.

How can I show $$|4x^2y-y-x|<17/16?$$

I tried, but no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to find extrema of $4x^2y-y-x$ for $x \in (-\frac12, \frac12)$ and $y\in [-1,1]$. Note the function is linear in $y$, so extrema will only be when $y\in \{-1, 1\}$.

Case $y=1$: we have $4(x-\frac18)^2-\frac{17}{16} \in [-\frac{17}{16}, \frac12)$

Case $y=-1$: we have $-4(x+\frac18)^2+\frac{17}{16} \in (-\frac12, \frac{17}{16}]$.

So we have $|4x^2y-y-x|\le \frac{17}{16}$. Note the inequality is **not** strict, $x=\pm\frac18, y=\pm1$ achieves the maximum.